# Trying to print one thing if found element in array, or print something else if not in array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to print one thing if a certain element is found within a for loop, or print something else if it's not found. This should be simple, but I've tried to do it many different ways, and none of them seem to work.

```
int squaresArray[1000];
int numberOfSquares = 1000;
int i = 0;
int found = 0;
int number = 100;

for (; i<numberOfSquares; i++)
{
    squaresArray[i] = i*i;
    if (number==squaresArray[i])
    {
        found = 1;
    }
            if (found == 1){
                printf("%d is a perfect square", number); 
                break;}
            else {
                printf("%d is not a perfect square", number);
                break;} 
    }
```

There are a couple of problems, the "found" variable goes out of scope outside of the if statement, so I can't do the printf part outside of the if statement, or it just prints "[number] is not a perfect square" dozens of times. How can I do this? I've spent hours on this problem.

Comment: Where you have declared `number`?

Comment: You may be using it outside of this code somewhere, but you don't need an array to tell whether a number is a perfect square or not.

Comment: "number" is entered by the user in main() and passed to this function as a parameter.

Comment: How else can I do it without populating an array with perfect squares or using math.h or similar?

Comment: @user2850602; Add your `main` function to the question.

Comment: @user2850602; Why `number = 100`? You said you are passing its value fron `main`? And show your function definition and its call in the `main`.

Comment: **Warning!** You're running through `0` to `1000`th **(1001)** element when the array contains **1000** elements.  Write: `for (; i<numberOfSquares - 1; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you are showing is very time consuming because You need to iterate thousand times if the number is square 999.

Use [`sqrt()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt) function from `math.h`to find whether the given number is perfect square are not

Give a try to this.

```
double param = 1024.0; //read different inputs with the help of scanf(). 
int i;

if ( ( (  i= (int) (sqrt(param)*10)  ) % 10) == 0 )  

      printf(" is a perfect square");
else
      printf(" is not a perfect square");
```

from @jongware comment,  this is tricky than above and easy to understand.

```
   if ( ((int)sqrt(param))*((int)sqrt(param))==param)  

          printf(" is a perfect square");
    else
          printf(" is not a perfect square");
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That works. I was trying to code it without using math.h, but I can use math.h. It seems to do the trick.

Comment: Most welcome.. if you have chance to use math.h you can use this.there is simple thing here find the sqrt of number, returns double value. check is there anything after decimal point.for more accurate result, in if statement multiply with 100 and find reminder with 100 or even go for multiplying with 1000 and find reminder with 1000.because if sqrt returns xx.01 the above one shows perfect square.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to check if `((int)sqrt(param))*((int)sqrt(param))` returns the original integer again? Then you are not left at the mercy of decimals. And surely the double `sqrt` will be optimized to a single one.

Comment: `((int)sqrt(param))*((int)sqrt(param))==param` made this quite easy .Thanks.

Comment: This should also work: `param % ((int)sqrt(param)) == 0`. It trades a sqrt for a div and looses the multiply.

Comment: This works if `param is int value`.here `param` is `double value` and passing double and int to `%`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int squaresArray[1000];
int numberOfSquares = 1000;
int i = 0;
int found = 0;
int number = 0;

for (; i<numberOfSquares; i++)
{
    squaresArray[i] = i*i;
    if (number==squaresArray[i]){
        found = 1;
        break;
     }
}
if (found == 1){
                printf("%d is a perfect square", number); 
                break;}
            else {
                printf("%d is not a perfect square", number);
                break; 
    }
```

Comment: `if (number==squaresArray[i])` will become false always after first iteration.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I think the "found" variable can't be accessed outside of the if statement, so it always seems to report that "number" is not a perfect square even when it is.

Comment: Your code will print `"%d [is/is not] a perfect square"` for only the 1st element: statement `if (found == 1)` doesn't belong to `for`-loop. Anyway, there are `break` statements which would cause exit from the `for`-loop if they were in it.

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm trying to print one thing if a certain element is found within a for loop, or print something else if it's not found*

Pseudocode:

```
int found = 0;
for each element e {
    if e is the one I'm looking for {
        found = 1
        stop the loop
    }
}
if (found)
    print one thing
else
    print something else
```

Comment: Yep, this one doesn't seem to work because the "found" variable goes out of scope outside the if statement and can't be accessed, so it always reports that the number isn't in the array even though printing the elements of the array proves that it actually is.

Comment: "the "found" variable goes out of scope outside the if statement" <-- that is not true.  Since you aren't declaring `found` inside the if statement (you didn't write `int found = 1;`, right???), and you are declaring `found` at the start of the whole function, it is in scope for the whole function.

Comment: @librik: Yes, you are correct. I couldn't seem to access the updated value of "found" outside of the if block, but now I can. Strange indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using library functions:

```
  int size = numberOfSquares / sizeof squaresArray[0];

  qsort(ints, size, sizeof(int), int_cmp);

  int *res = bsearch(&number, squaresArray, size, sizeof(squaresArrays[0]), int_cmp);

  if (res == NULL) {
        printf("%d not found\n", number);
  } 
  else {
        printf("got %d:\n", *res);
  }
```

You also need to provide the comparison function:

```
int int_cmp(const void* a, const void* b) {
    const int *arg1 = a;
    const int *arg2 = b;
    return *arg1 - *arg2;
}
```

Comment: What does the "key" variable refer to in the first printf statement?

Comment: just a typo, it should have been the number you search for

Answer (score 0):

***"I was trying to code it without using math.h"***

**Here is the solution without using `<math.h>` library.**

I suppose, you know that there is the only *"perfect square"* that your program can find :)
Anyway, see the comments: they will describe something.

Use `continue` instead of `break` in order not to break the `for`-loop.

```
    int squaresArray[1000];
    int numberOfSquares = 999;
    int i;
    int found = 0;
    int number = 100;


    for ( i = 0 ; i < numberOfSquares; i++ )
    {
        squaresArray[i] = i*i;
        if (number == squaresArray[i])
            found = 1;
        else
            found = 0;

        if (found == 1){
            printf("%d is a perfect square", number);
            continue;   // Skipping the current loop and incrementing the `i` variable
        }
        else {
         // printf("%d is not a perfect square", number); 
         /* If you remove the slashes, you'll see 999 "N is not a perfect square"s,
            so you see why I've marked it as comment :) */
            continue;   // Skipping the current loop and incrementing the `i` variable
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int squaresArray[1000];
int numberOfSquares = 1000;
int i;
int found = 0;
int number = 100;

for (i=0; i<numberOfSquares; i++){
    squaresArray[i] = i*i;

    if (number==squaresArray[i]){
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
 }

if (found == 1){
      printf("%d is a perfect square of %d\n", number,i); 
}else {
      printf("%d is not a perfect square", number);

}
return 0;
}
```

**this gives me the following output:**

```
100 is a perfect square of 10
```

Is this what is desired?

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks. I don't know why I couldn't access the "found" variable outside of the if statement before, but this does work.

Comment: iT didn't work because you were never letting the loop go further than 1st iteration. ... In your else statement you had a `break` command .. so in the first iteration  - found is not equal to 1 so your loop goes into else statement and breaks out... there should be no break in your else statement. .. Also please accept the answer if you are satisfied